# Restore Fragment with WebView without reloading the webview content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-architecture-navigation, android-fragment-manager

I’m happy to learn that the **navigation library** finally saves and restores Fragment state since version **2.4** ([release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_240_3) ), which is useful in a **Bottom Navigation** scenario to not completely rebuild screens when switching tabs.

**Before**, I would resort to a not-so-great subclass of FragmentNavigator that would **detach / re-attach** the Fragments, to retain it completely, including scroll-position etc.
I would be super happy to get rid of this custom subclass, but I ran into this problem:

**Now**, When switching to a Fragment that contains a WebView (I know, :disappointed: ), the webview will reload when I select the tab that contains it, even when using webView.restoreState() (this will only restore what url was loaded last along with the navigation history, I believe)

Has anyone figured out how to completely retain a WebView ’s state when switching tabs? That is, without any reloading going on?

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but I don't believe this is possible anymore. From the API documentation for `WebView.restoreState()`:

`Please note that this method no longer restores the display data for this WebView.`

Hopefully I'm wrong, because I would also prefer to not reload the content when restoring state.